# iOS Swift doesn't pass data back via delegation

Tags: ios, swift, segue, delegation

I'm segueing from one view controller to another like so:

```
    switch popIndex {

    case 301:
        let destVC = segue.destination as! IDPopoverViewController
        destVC.popIndex = popIndex
        destVC.titleString = "Issuer or Category"
...
```

In the second VC, the user enters data `(String)`. I'm passing this data back to the originating VC via delegation:

```
        case 301:
            newIssuerDelegate?.appendName(name: dataToReturn)
            print("In delegate call, dataToReturn = \(dataToReturn)")
...
```

**The delegate function:**

```
func appendName(name:String) {
    newIssuer.name = name
    issuerNameLabel.text = name
    print("In appendName, name = \(name)")
    saveIt()
}
```

**The Protocol**

```
protocol NewIssuerProtocol {
    func appendName(name:String)
...
```

**The Problem:**

The data seemingly never arrives at the delegate function. The data doesn't appear on `issuerNameLabel`, nor in the `print` statement. Doesn't crash, just returns to the originating VC and idles, awaiting another command.

I've placed breakpoints in the delegate call (stops, as expected), and in the delegate function. the receipt of the data isn't acknowledged by the breakpoint, nor by the `print` statement. I should mention that none of the (6) other delegate functions in the same protocol appear to receive or display the relevant data, either. However, several similarly constructed delegation schemes throughout the app are working just fine.

**My Plea**

Can someone spot what I'm doing wrong on this one?

All help much appreciated!

**Fix**

I neglected to set the delegate when preparing for the segue, as was generously pointed out below by @vadian!

```
    case 301:
        let destVC = segue.destination as! IDPopoverViewController
        destVC.popIndex = popIndex
        destVC.titleString = "Issuer or Category"
        destVC.newIssuerDelegate = self
```

Comment: Where do you set the delegate? By the way in Swift a callback closure is a better choice.

Comment: I set it in the second VC, i.e.:     var newIssuerDelegate : NewIssuerProtocol? = nil

Comment: That's the declaration and the delegate is set to `nil`. You have to set the delegate to the target view controller `destVC.newIssuerDelegate = self`

Comment: Many thanks, sir! Just plain dumb oversight. I have corrected it above in an edit to my question. Thanks again for taking the time! Thought I was losing my mind... :)